# Get text of an element before its containing span tag in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want the text in 2 variables like :

```
var a = "Bar" ;   
var b = "by year" ;
```

Html:

```
<h5 class="heading">Bar<span class="cT">by year</span></h5>
```

Comment: You can use simple properties of the elements like `h5Elem.firstChild` - will return first child of the `H5` which is `TextNode` and then `h5Elem.firstElementChild.textContent;` which returns first HTML element of the `H5` which is `span` and the you get its `textContent `.

Comment: okay @Krusader.., thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For first variable, You can get the text node using:

```
var a = $('.heading').contents().filter(function() {
 return this.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE; 
}).text();
```

for second element:

```
var b = $('.ct').text();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use destructuring assignment to get `.firstChild` and `.textContent` properties of `.heading` `.childNodes`

```js
let {0: {textContent: a}, 1: {firstChild: {textContent: b}}} = document.querySelector(".heading").childNodes;

console.log(`a:${a}, b:${b}`);
```

```html
<h5 class="heading">Bar<span class="cT">by year</span></h5>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming h5 only has 2 nodes that contain text.

You could try the following (no jQuery needed only to create the html element)

```js
var $content = $(`
<h5 class="heading">
  Bar
  <span class="cT">
    by year
  </span>
</h5>`);
var [a,b] = 
  []
  .map.call(
    $content[0].childNodes
    ,x=>x.textContent
  )
  .map(x=>x.trim())
  .filter(x=>x!=="")
;
alert("a is:"+a);
alert("b is:"+b);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another option to solve this problem:

```
let a = jQuery(".heading").clone().find('span').remove().end().text();

let b = jQuery(".heading > span").text()
```

Regarding `a` a clone is performed and then the span is removed from the clone and the text of the manipulated clone is captured.

Regarding `b` the text of the direct `span` child of `.heading` is extracted.